# Enable/Disable dropdown - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code where 2 drop downs are available on the UI. When I select value "1" of drop down 1, the drop down 2 should be disabled. When I select value "1", the dropdown 2 is disabled. But I am not able to re-enable the drop down 2 when the user select value "2" from drop down 1. I am not sure since I am calling the `performValidation()` method for `onClick` event of both the options in drop down 1.

Code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<script = "text/javascript">
     function performValidation()
     {
           if (document.mainForm.criteriaOne.value == "1")
           {
                document.mainForm.criteriaTwo.options.length = 0;
                document.mainForm.criteriaTwo.disabled = true;
           }
           else
                document.mainForm.criteriaTwo.disabled = false;
     }
</script>
<body>
        <form name="mainForm" action= "" method ="get">
              Criteria One:<select id = "criteriaOne">
             <option value = "1" onClick ="performValidation()"> Select One - One</option>
             <option value = "2" onClick ="performValidation()"> Select one - Two</option>
              </select>
              Criteria Two:<select id = "criteriaTwo">
             <option value = "1" onClick ="performValidation()"> Select Two - One</option>
              </select>
         </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure, your code works for me as is in Firefox 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wire up a function to the onchange event on the select something like

```
document.getElementById("criteriaOne").onchange = function() 
         { // do some work to check the selectedIndex and determine whether to re-                enable the other drop down}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need

```
document.mainForm.criteriaTwo.options.length = 0;
```

Comment: presence/absence of that line doesn't solve my problem however  !